# 3rd party controls for MS SQL 2005 Reporting Services

Tags: reporting-services, reportingservices-2005

Can anyone recommend a good 3rd party control(s) for MS SQL 2005 Reporting Services. If you know some open library or implementation of such controls that could be very useful too.

Comment: What do you need the controls to do???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dundas do great RS add-ins if you have the budget:

http://www.dundas.com/index.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I agree, Dundas has great controls. I used it in one of my projects.

This was the sample which I used to test out the CRI:
http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTRSProdSamples/Wiki/View.aspx?title=SS2005%21Custom%20Report%20Item%20Sample&referringTitle=Home